# Catching a compile error in a subroutine in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I would really appreciate help on this one.
We are making some applications in Excel VBA at work and sometimes, a routine in one file calls a routine in another file.

```
Application.Run ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!SomeOtherRoutine"
```

My problem is, that the other routine has a compile error (End If is missing). So the whole process broke down, of course. But being a compile error, this error can't be trapped by the error handler.

Is there a way to catch this kind of error, so my code doesn't get interrupted?

Comment: Have you tried running the subroutine on it's own? I.e. kicking it of yourself rather than it being kicked off by the initial routine.

Comment: can you post the function code causing the error, best way would be to fix it.

Comment: No, I didn't, that was a subroutine written by my collaegue. Obviously he didn't run it by himself and I trusted him :-D I know, this can be solved by testing the subroutine itself, but in this case it hasn't been done. My question is solely on the purpose, if I can catch such an error of human failure.

Comment: Nope - the error handler is there to catch run-time errors. Compile errors have to be fixed _prior_ to the code being run. You can manually compile the module by going to Debug -> Compile and check that way.

Comment: Kind of expected answer, but heartbreaking nevertheless. Thank you very much.

Comment: As for Jason and Nathan, we did fix the subroutine easily, it wasn't a long one. But my thanks goes to you, too, for giving my queastion attention :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually compile the project before you start using it. This way, you can scan the whole code for syntax errors, and leave other types of errors to be handled by your code handler.